# Big O or Omega?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Good day,

I am going over a problem sheet right now and I can not seem to figure out the last combination of functions and their bounds.

We are given,

> $f_1(n) = \dfrac{n^3}{log(n)}, \ f_2(n)=n^9+2.2^n \text{ and } g_1(n)=(n+1)^3, \ g_2(n)=2^n+2^{\frac{n}{2}}$
>
> Decide whether the different combinations are $f_i=O(g_j(n))  \ \text{and/or} \ f_i=\Omega(g_j(n)).$

What I got so far is that $f_1=O(g_1),\ f_1=O(g_2), \ f_2=\Omega(g_1)$

I am stuck on the combination $f_2, \ g_2$.

I am not sure what I can do to show that it works because of $2.2^n$

Comment: I assume you already know that $2^{\frac n2}$ is unimportant here since it equals $\sqrt{2^n}$ and so is asymptotically insignificant compared to the term $2^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent it by $e$ and $\log2$, $\log(2.2)$:

$\dfrac{f_2(n)}{g_2(n)}= \dfrac{n^9+(2.2)^n}{2^n+2^{\frac{n}{2}}} \geq \dfrac{(2.2)^n}{2^n+2^{\frac{n}{2}}}\geq \dfrac{(2.2)^n}{2\cdot 2^n} =\frac{1}{2}e^{n(\log2.2-\log2)}$

And similarly:

$\dfrac{f_2(n)}{g_2(n)}= \dfrac{n^9+(2.2)^n}{2^n+2^{\frac{n}{2}}} \leq \dfrac{2\cdot(2.2)^n}{2^n}\leq 2e^{n(\log2.2-\log2)}$

Comment: Is it okay that the upper/lower bound depends on $n$?

Perhaps I did not fully understand the notion of $O$ and $\Omega$

Comment: @ʎpoqou: In what way do you mean *depends* on $n$? The definition of $f=O(g)$ says that for $n$ large enough, say larger than some $n_0$, the relation $f(n)\leq M g(n)$ holds independently of the specific choice of $n$ at that point.

Comment: The last inequality appears to be wrong. Did you mean $$\frac{g_2(n)}{f_2(n)}\leq 2\operatorname{e}^{-n(\log 2.2-\log 2)}$$

Comment: I've added by edit where I think the last inequality stems from. And obviously the inequalities are true only from some point onwards.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: Ah, sure! I see it now. Essentially you have established that $f_2$ over $g_2$ is Big Theta of some exponential expression which does make sense! Sorry for misunderstanding that!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have $a>b>1$. Then
$$
\frac{a^n}{b^n}=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n=(1+r)^n
$$
for some $r>0$ and this grows exponentially as $n$ tends to infinity. Thus $a^n$ wins out asymptotically although $b^n$ also tends to infinity.